# Program to display matrix zigzag

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, logic

I need to display in zigzag a matrix. like that:
the size of the matrix: 3 3

```
00 01 02 
10 11 12 
20 21 22 
30 31 32
```

display: `00 01 02 12 11 10 20 21[...]`

Here's my code but it displays some random numbers in the middle:

```
int lines, columns;
cin>> lines >>columns;
int matriz[lines][columns];

for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j){
        cin >> matrix[i][j];
    }
}
int j=0;
for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i){
    if (i%2==0){
        while(j<columns){
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<' ';
            j++;
        }
    }else{
        while(j>=0){
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<' ';
            j--;
        }

    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: You probably went out of bounds on `j`. Check that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `int matriz[lines][columns];` is a Variable Length Array and not kosher C++. C++ requires that all array dimensions be known at compile time. GCC breaks the standard and allows it, but be certain that `lines*column` does not exceed your Automatic storage size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the else case, `j` equals `columns` at the start of the while loop (so at the next line, `matrix[i][j]` will be out of bounds, because `j` should be strictly less than `columns`). A simple fix would be to change `while(j>=0)` to `while(j>0)` and move `j--` before `cout`.

But, as the others say, you should learn to use the debugger, it is very easy to catch such errors with it.

Comment: Bit faster than me. I'll drop my demo/proof here: http://ideone.com/vOR0ie

Comment: Hey to use the highlighting, use the character beside number 1, which is the ` and not the single quotation '. Hope this helps